# Regular expression, match between the first, second, third etc. occurences of a pair of words

Tags: r, regex

I would like to find a regular expression that matches the bold text in the string below.

"A1 text: **XXX** \r\n Status: **No** \r\n Info: **YYYY \r\n UUUU** End A2 text: **BBB** \r\n Status: **Yes** \r\n Info: **VVV \r\n OOO** End A3 2020/2021"

My problem is the match between the pair "Info" and "End. My regex below matches everything between the first occurence of "Info" and the last of "End". I want it to match the first "Info" and the next "End". Thereafter the next "Info" and the "End" that comes after.

```
string <- "A1 text: XXX \r\n Status: No \r\n Info: YYYY \r\n UUUU End A2 text: BBB \r\n Status: Yes \r\n Info: VVV \r\n OOO End A3 2020/2021"

str_match_all(string, regex("text: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?Status: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.",
                           dotall=T))[[1]][,-1]

str_match_all(string, regex("(?<=Info)(.*)(?=End)",
                            dotall=T))[[1]][,-1]


I want a expression like this: 
str_match_all(string, regex("text: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?Status: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?(?<=Info)(.*)(?=End)",   dotall=T))[[1]][,-1]

to return this:

     [,1]   [,2]  [,3]
[1,] "XXX " "No " "YYYY \r\n UUUU"
[2,] "BBB " "Yes " "VVV \r\n OOO"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
string <- "A1 text: XXX \r\n Status: No \r\n Info: YYYY \r\n UUUU End A2 text: BBB \r\n Status: Yes \r\n Info: VVV \r\n OOO End A3 2020/2021"
library(stringr)
res <- str_match_all(string, "(?s)text:\\h*(.*?)\\R\\s*Status:\\h*(.*?)\\R\\s*Info:\\h*(.*?)\\s*End\\b")
lapply(res, function(m) m[,-1])
# => [[1]]
# =>      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]            
# => [1,] "XXX " "No "  "YYYY \r\n UUUU"
# => [2,] "BBB " "Yes " "VVV \r\n OOO"
```

The regex is

```js
(?s)text:\h*(.*?)\R\s*Status:\h*([^\r\n]*)\R\s*Info:\h*(.*?)\s*End\b
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RjVjim/1). Details:

- `(?s)` - the inline dotall modifier
- `text:` - literal text
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\R` - any line break sequence
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespaces
- `Status:\h*` - `Status:` and 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `([^\r\n]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than CR and LF
- `\R` - any line break sequence
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespaces
- `Info:\h*` - `Info:` and 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\s*End\b` - 0+ whitespaces, `End` as a whole word.

Comment: Thanks! Amazing. One question: Why dosent it work with ,dotall=T))[[1]][,-1]? Why do I need lapply?

Comment: @Henrik `str_match_all(string, "(?s)text:\\h*(.*?)\\R\\s*Status:\\h*(.*?)\\R\\s*Info:\\h*(.*?)\\s*End\\b")[[1]][,-1]` works fine on my end. Did you re-assign `T`? Never use `T`, always use full form `TRUE`.